# How do I overwrite the ESC key pressed behavior for jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a form submit when pressed in which I am showing a small jQuery dialog with a spinning wheel. When I press escape, the dialog closes which is interrupting my form submission. How do I overcome by the user when they press ESC key. How do I prevent the user exiting when the ESC key is pressed for jQuery dialog?

Comment: Did any answer solved your question? Please mark the one that solved your problem as the right answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for 
 http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-closeOnEscape

Answer (score 41):

use the [closeOnEscape](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-closeOnEscape) option

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ closeOnEscape: false });
```

Comment: Both a link to the documentation and an example, nice!